# ORM for simple .NET app

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, orm

I need to develop a .NET 4 application with an MS SQL Server 2008 database. There will be about 5-6 "classes." I am familiar with developing applications in Python/SqlAlchemy ORM.

Is there any simple mechanism to do the following tasks?

- create classes and their dependencies
- automatically create database tables and query classes in C#

Comment: I'm sorry, but you need to google that yourself since theres a lot of different ORMs that can do that. Which makes this question highly subjective.

Comment: @jgauffin: [Just making sure you know the memo.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers)

Comment: @Bobby: Did you read my entire comment?

Comment: @jgauffin: Yes, I did, that's why I said `Just making sure`. I just wanted to make sure you know about that, if you do, it's fine with me.

Comment: @Bobby He meant the "subjective" part (as he's [posted on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90928/is-recommend-me-xxx-subjective-questions))

Comment: How is this subjective and argumentative? Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Entity Framework 4.1 "Code First"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723). It lets you describe the data model in code, and as you say, then let magic happen.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to check out Entity Framework. In the new version, 4.1, there is a feature called Code-First that does what you describe.

ScottGu has a great [blogpost](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) explaining it:

Answer (score 2):

For simple project you can use: [SubSonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/) - it's easy to use with only few dlls. It has also easy learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

My preference for ORM in .NET is Entity Framework 4. It can easily create the classes from your database schema, and combined with LINQ it's a powerful combination.

You can find a link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723).

Answer (score 0):

You should also look at [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata) - it works in with Entity Fx for Scaffolding even UI. Great for small data-entry applications where you don't want very specific UI.